# how to add altarnative layout for landscape in android

Tags: android

I want to know how to use an altarnative layout to use it if the user use his phone in a landscape mode, how to make my app has a good diminsions for this mode ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use folder like below in your `res` folder

- layout-small-land
- layout-normal-land
- layout-large-land
- layout-xlarge-land

Answer (score 2):

You should add layout-land folder and add a file with same name according to layout.

Answer (score 1):

Add a `layout-land` folder in the `res` folder. If the device is in landscape mode, it will first look into the `layout-land` folder for the right layout. If it can't be found there, it will look in the default `layout` folder.

You could also work the other way around and create a `layout-port` folder and put your portrait layouts in there.

More information on this can be found [here](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/supporting-devices/screens.html)